# Meaning of the phrase "I could tell"

Tags: can-could

Context:

---

I was so happy I felt tears starting in my eyes, and then she up and hugged me.
I think she could tell.

Comment: I think this is Off Topic General Reference. From the first online dictionary I looked at - [**tell** : to find out by observing, recognize *<you can tell it's a masterpiece>*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tell* is frequently used with the meaning of *realize* or *understand*, so the sentence you quote can be read as

"As I was close to tears, and she ***realized*** it, she came near me and hugged me"